# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower' in tockenizer_left.texts_to_sequences(x_left)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tokenize

I'm tried split my data on tokens. All data in lower case. 
I'd like to build Manhattan LSTM model.

I've try to add some parameter in my Tokenizer().
For example:

num_words=max_nb_words

filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~'

lower=True

```py
max_nb_words = 50000
max_seq_length = max(max([len(s) for s in x_left]),max([len(s) for s in x_right]))

tockenizer_left = Tokenizer(num_words=max_nb_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tockenizer_left.fit_on_texts(data_train['Data_Name_left'].values)


x_left_tokens = tockenizer_left.texts_to_sequences(x_left)
x_left_pad = pad_sequences(tockenizer_left, maxlen=max_seq_length)

tockenizer_right = Tokenizer()
tockenizer_right.fit_on_texts(data_train['Data_Name_right'].values)

x_right_tokens = tockenizer_right.texts_to_sequences(x_right)
x_right_pad = pad_sequences(x_right_tokens,xlen=max_seq_length)

vocab_size = max(len(tockenizer_left.word_index) +1, len(tockenizer_right.word_index) +1)
```

I expected text sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - Tockenizer(lower=False)